# How to remove duplicated sets from a list and get the first element in R?

Tags: r, list, unique, lapply

I have a list of vectors where each vector contains different numbers of numeric strings, e.g.

```
A <- list(c(2,3,1,5),c(4,3,1),c(1,4,3),c(3,4,2,1))
```

I would like to remove duplicated vectors, such that the result would be

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

I am doing that by `unique(lapply(A, function(x) sort(unlist(x))))`, but I need to save the first element of each unique vector not sorted, that is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can apply `duplicated` to get the logical index after `sort`ing, use that to subset the `list`

```
A1 <- A[!duplicated(lapply(A, sort))]
```

and get the first element

```
lapply(A1, `[`, 1)
```

---

Or use `unique` if we need the `sort`ed elements

```
unique(lapply(A, sort))
```